# Oracle APEX 5.1 Custom form issue

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a form that contains a select list (:P10_DROPDOWN) that has its values defined via SQL:

```
SELECT
    display_name,
    value_id
FROM
    vw_dropdown_options;
```

As a pre-render-before-header-process I have the following PL/SQL to pre-populate :P10_DROPDOWN:

```
begin
    SELECT value_id
    INTO :P10_DROPDOWN
    FROM vw_dropdown_option_mapping
    WHERE vw_dropdown_option_mapping_id = :P10_DROPDOWN_OPTION_MAPPING_ID;
end;
```

At this point my form appears on my page, and everything looks okay.  However I need to have a custom procedure fire when a user clicks a button, so on a button on my page I defined an onClick event to fire this pl/sql block:

```
APEX_DEBUG.INFO ('P10_DROPDOWN_OPTION_MAPPING_ID ' || :10_DROPDOWN_OPTION_MAPPING_ID);
APEX_DEBUG.INFO ('P10_DROPDOWN ' || :P10_DROPDOWN);
NP_SAVE_MAPPING_VALUE (
    DROPDOWN_OPTION_MAPPING_ID => :P10_DROPDOWN_OPTION_MAPPING_ID,
    NEW_DROPDOWN_VALUE_ID => :P10_DROPDOWN
);
```

This is where I first notice my issue; the value logged out by the onClick for :P10_DROPDOWN is what was originally set via my pre-render-before-header-process, and not the value I select via my drop-down.

I have tried setting the source.used value on my dropdown to both "Always" and "Only".  I have also replaced my pre-render-before-header-process with a source based single value SQL query.  Neither is allowing my dropdown to change the session value via the dropdown.

Am I missing something about these session values?

Comment: As an aside; the stored procedure works when run on its own.  I can also get it to work if I use a AJAX request, but this seems way too heavy handed just to kick off a simple stored proc when a field is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is because newly selected value isn't in *session state*. To test it, create a SUBMIT button, push it, and then check the result again.

Just asking: did you consider

- setting item's *default value* (instead of writing a process to pre-populate it)
- using a *dynamic action* (instead of creating an onClick event)